# "pre span.org" css tag for the foreground color of the main text in the code

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting, org-mode

To understand my problem, please have a look at [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7629/the-syntax-highlight-and-indentation-of-source-code-block-in-exported-html-file/21781#21781) where there are multiple css tags for org mode, that the author lists. I have played successfully with all the span.org- tags and used them to modify syntax highlighting of various categories of text such as function-name using rgb-decimal method of color designation as an example below.

```
pre span.org-function-name               {color:rgb(255,000,255);}
```

However, I fail to find a span.org- tag which will allow me to change the color of the main text of the code which is invariably black in color. Even tracing that css for any color close to black shows no black color and no span.org- tag which means its not listed and must be included in the css to get a handle on that text. How does a newbie like me go about finding such a tag since I don't even know org-mode but use emacs semi-well including lisp functions? Also, ***please provide*** this newbie the desired tag so I can include it in the css file above. I tried adding a "foreground" tag similar to this background but that also did not work. Maybe, there is a way to specify the default text attributes, ie the text that is not tokenized as function-name etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below to your CSS to change the default foreground color:

```css
/* Default foreground color = red */
pre {color:#FF0000;}
```

I just googled "CSS foreground color" to learn this.

Comment: It works, but please also show me what you googled since I said that as a css and html newbie, I dont understand the nomenclature and system of these names.

Comment: Also an explanation why foreground does not work as I suggested to convert the background instance to it. Basically, where such tags are found/defined for the purpose that they are.

Comment: I already mentioned what I had googled. As to "why foreground does not work", it's just CSS syntax. I just googled to learn that the required keyword is `color`, not `foreground-color`.